# UIButton IBAction button name

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I wish to know the name of the button that was just tapped. I have this code so far:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"%@",sender);
}
```

However, this just returns a lot of jargon. Is there a way to return the name of the button that was just tapped?

Comment: the ivar of that button, so `IBOutlet UIButton *buttonName` I want "buttonName"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know the name just so you know what button has been clicked, I don't think you can get the name of the iVar, but there are other ways of doing this:

You can get the title of the button:

```
NSString *btnTitle = [sender currentTitle];
```

Alternatively - You can set a tag for the button in the Interface Builder view

```
NSInteger btnTag = [sender tag];
```

Comment: by setting a title for my buttons I can identify which has been clicked. Thank you Abizem

Answer (score 1):

You could use [the Objective-C runtime functions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) but this might be difficult.

---

What I recommend instead is setting the `tag` property for each button, and create an array with the names of each button, like this:

```
button1.tag = 0;
button2.tag = 1;
NSArray *buttonNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"button1", @"button2", nil];
```

In your method:

```
- (IBAction)buttonTap:(id)sender { // one cannot *click* on an iOS device
  NSLog(@"%@", [buttonNames objectAtIndex:[(UIButton *)sender tag]);
}
```

Comment: Hi Radek, thanks for your help. I'm getting `Request for member 'tag' is not a structure or union` - also, noted about the tap/click difference - I'm just a web-developer making ground in the iOS world, old habits die hard.

Comment: @Daniel Hanly I updated the answer. It should compile now. :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
NSLog(@"%@",[sender title]);
```

Comment: And this is not what was asked. The Ivar name was asked.

Comment: oh im sorry, i didnt saw the comments on his own question.